# Selenimum Using Selenium to locate an an attribute and click the dynamic link associated with the image

Tags: c#, selenium-rc

I am new to Selenium and coding.  What I am trying to do is click a dynamic link.  Here is the scenario.

I have to find a dynamic link in a div that has multiple links.

The link I want to click has the myimage attribute and the link will always be different.  There can be N-links in the div and some of the links won't have the myimage attribute.

I can locate the div using XPath, but I am having trouble finding the link I want in the div

In short, I want to look through the list of dynamic links in a div, find a link that has the myimage class and click it.

Can someone suggest a reference or provide a code snippet on how to do this with Selenium using C#?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you have the latest version of selenium.

All you need is to extend the XPath you have for the div to include the link with the attribute.  I haven't tried this in code but should work:

Selenium.Click("xpath=//a[@class='myimage']")

Check [this](http://www.theautomatedtester.co.uk/tutorials/selenium/selenium_xpath.htm) article for more details

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.  Here's what actually worked since the link and image are siblings in a parent node.  

selenium.Click("xpath=//img[@class='myimage']/../a");

Comment: Can I ask if my answer was of help could you mark it as the answer. Cheers.